# RabbitMQ - different dead-letter exchange for rejected messages and max-length

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a queue with the `max length` parameter set, as per https://www.rabbitmq.com/maxlength.html. For this queue, a dead-letter exchange is also defined.

I noted that both rejected messages and messages which have been removed when the maximum length was reached end up in the dead-letter exchange.

Is it possible to define multiple dead-letter exchanges? One for rejected messages, one for purged messages.

**update**

I would not mind that purged messages are silently discarded, instead of forwarded to the dead-letter exchange. This way, only the rejected messages end up in the dead-letter exchange. Is that possible?

Comment: I was thinking about declaring DLX exchange as `headers` exchange and then route messages based on `x-death.reason` (with `x-match = any` argument set on binding) to specific queue. The only issue is that I'm not quite sure routing on nested headers list is possible (at least I can't make it work from management panel quickly).

Comment: I was thinking in the same region, but I do not think routing on nested headers is possible :(.

Comment: Given the fact that I am not getting any responses, I guess this is not possible.

Comment: You don't need separate exchanges for this, you can simply add a dead-letter-routing-key, you can bind different queues to the exchange, and based on the routing key, they'll end up on separate queues. I think this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do with the messages afterwards. In my case, I needed to discard the "purged" messages because I just wanted to republish the nacked messages to the tail of the same queue, so that they are retried after the rest of the messages are processed.

Turns out RabbitMQ already contemplates this use case. From [RabbitMQ docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html#routing):

> It is possible to form a cycle of message dead-lettering. For instance, this can happen when a queue dead-letters messages to the default exchange without specifiying a dead-letter routing key. Messages in such cycles (i.e. messages that reach the same queue twice) will be dropped if there was no rejections in the entire cycle.

So, if you create the circle, only messages rejected are really going to be rerouted to the queue, and the purged messages won't.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up RabbitMQ to route messages through a Dead Letter Exchange based on the death reason (either `x-death.reason` or `x-first-death-reason`).

You should to set up an Dead Letter Exchange with `type=headers` to be able to route by the value of these headers and `x-match` should be `any-with-x` or `all-with-x` to be able match `x-` headers.

From documentation about [exchange-headers](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html#exchange-headers):

> For `any` and `all`, headers beginning with the string `x-` will not be
> used to evaluate matches. Setting `x-match` to `any-with-x` or
> `all-with-x` will also use headers beginning with the string `x-` to
> evaluate matches.

Something like on this:

[image: rabbitmq dlx.text exchange setup]